# mySQL problems with this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with this code and hoping someone can help.

Basically we have an issue whereby mySQL is running out of connections when this script is run hundreds of times in sequence.

https://gist.github.com/anthonyTS/b6c46d54ee8bf2d714b8

Here is the database class:

https://gist.github.com/anthonyTS/89f5a831e31d970fb5e1

Here is the error I get:

```
E_ERROR: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

Stack Trace:

```
in DB::single called at /var/www/html/scripts/stalk/db.php (68)
in DB::single called at /var/www/html/scripts/stalk/beanstalk_check_monitoring_logs.php (88)
in {closure} called at /var/www/html/application/libraries/Stalk.php (80)
in Stalk::background called at /var/www/html/scripts/stalk/
```

beanstalk_check_monitoring_logs.php (188)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your DB initialization:

```
 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
 $DB = new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
```

above your:

```
$stalk = new Stalk(array(BEANSTALKD_SERVER, BEANSTALKD_PORT));
```

on the top of script, to create DB conncetion just once but not in loop `while(true)` - that is really bad idea :-)

and since you use some weird to me function declaration:

```
$stalk->background(function() {
   $tube = 'check-monitoring-logs';
   ...
```

You can call DB instance like:

```
$stalk->background(function() {
   global $DB;
   $tube = 'check-monitoring-logs';
   ...
```

and replace all calls of `DB::` to `$DB->` .